# Custom LinearLayout - childs not visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I build customView extending LinearLayout and having simple 3 childrens(2 TextView and ImageView). I create this view dynamically in code and adding it to parent LinearLayout. This view has background, so I can easily spot on the screen, that it is inflated correctly in its place, but any of child is not visible. I checked LayoutInspector and it shows that everything is setted correctly(text values to TextViews and picture to ImageView), but somehow when I try to locate them on inspector they are shown as little dot over my customView:

[image]

My CustomView is called DayTileView and this is square with gray background. As you can see on inspector on the left childrens are filled with content. Layout of View:

```
 <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <merge>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/day"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dayName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/padlock"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_padlock"
    />
</merge>
</layout>
```

And its code:

```
public class DayTileView extends LinearLayout {
private DayTileBinding mBinding;

public DayTileView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public DayTileView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public DayTileView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()), R.layout.day_tile, this, true);
    setOrientation(VERTICAL);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int width = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
}

public void setDay(int day, int month, int year) {
    DateTime settedDay = new DateTime().withYear(year).withMonthOfYear(month).withDayOfMonth(day);
    mBinding.day.setText(String.valueOf(day));
    String dayName = settedDay.dayOfWeek().getAsText();
    mBinding.dayName.setText(dayName);
    boolean isWeekend = settedDay.dayOfWeek().get() == 6 || settedDay.dayOfWeek().get() == 7;
    setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), isWeekend ? R.color.weekend_bg : R.color.weekday_bg));
}
```

}

Its use in another CustomView which is also LinearLayout but wiht horizontal orientation (PlannedDayView on inspector):

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <merge>

        <*.customViews.DayTileView
                android:id="@+id/dayTile"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1.2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </merge>
</layout>
```

Has anyone any idea what could be casuing this (childs out of view)? When I replace merge for LinearLayout with vertical orientation and same background everything in Design mode of layout is visible correctly, so it should work.

EDIT:
I found out, that if I set during View initalization Padding Top to 10px then dot is moving down. So it looks like from some reasons Android didn't made to inflate correctly TextViews and ImageView

Comment: Try to remove <layout tag "xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  and move this two properties to "<merge" , which is supposed to be root..

Comment: I moved namespace declarations to merge, but it doesn't help. I cannot delete layout tag, beacuse I wouldn't get any binding. All my customViews are made in this manner and they are working. Only this one is messy

Comment: Ok, what about weights, if you try different weights in DayTileView.

Comment: If you mean inside layout of DayTileView i tried to set height to 0dp and weight 1 for every view. Inside init() setLayoutWeightSum for 3f and still nothing changed :(

Comment: Even changing textSizes and layoutWidth and Height to constant values like 15dp or 30dp doesn't change anything. Those views bahaving like ghosts - In inspector they have everything, but on screen nothing

Comment: What about textColor on textViews?? It's set on white.. and your background is also white..

Comment: @mmmatey this is not matter of color. Outline of those views doesn't exist - only as dot. If I set margin top to eg 10dp dot representing three views is moving down. But for sake I tried every combination - different size, black color , letting only image view, only one text view. And background is green or gray(depending of weekend or not) and for both is not visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was the problem:
I overrided onMeasure and didn't measure child Views. Earlier I was using such code to make square View not square ViewGroup.

Corrected code:

```
 final int width = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
    super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
```

After setting correct width and height for View I must measure whole view with new MeasureSpec